# Java (add data to a xml file without overwrite)

Tags: java, xml

I am practicing with Java Swing and I am doing a menu item that saves the data on a xml, adding the content without overwriting... the matter is that it seems that for any mistake it always delete all the xml except the first child of root, and then appends the data correctly...

Here is the xml (with test data)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <Settings>
      <Setting>
         <Name>r</Name>
         <Channel>r</Channel>
         <Amp>r</Amp>
         <Effects>r</Effects>
         <Pregain>r</Pregain>
         <Low>r</Low>
         <Mid>r</Mid>
         <High>r</High>
         <Postgain>r</Postgain>
         <Param1>r</Param1>
         <Param2>r</Param2>
         <Feedback>r</Feedback>
         <Level>r</Level>
         <Reverb>r</Reverb>
      </Setting>
      <Setting>
         <Name>d</Name>
         <Channel>d</Channel>
         <Amp>d</Amp>
         <Effects>d</Effects>
         <Pregain>d</Pregain>
         <Low>d</Low>
         <Mid>d</Mid>
         <High>d</High>
         <Postgain>d</Postgain>
         <Param1>d</Param1>
         <Param2>d</Param2>
         <Feedback>d</Feedback>
         <Level>d</Level>
         <Reverb>d</Reverb>
      </Setting>
    </Settings>
```

And here is the java code

```
menuitemsave = new JMenuItem("Save");
    menuitemsave.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

              try {

                DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();   

                // Read XML
                Document document = docBuilder.parse("Settings.xml");

                // Root - Settings
                Element root = document.getDocumentElement();

                // Element - Setting
                Element Setting = document.createElement("Setting");
                root.appendChild(Setting);

                // Attribute - Name
                Element Name = document.createElement("Name");
                Name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txtname.getText()));
                Setting.appendChild(Name);

                // Attribute - Channel
                Element Channel = document.createElement("Channel");
                Channel.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txtchannel.getText()));
                Setting.appendChild(Channel);

                // Attribute - Amp
                Element Amp = document.createElement("Amp");
                Amp.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txtamp.getText()));
                Setting.appendChild(Amp);

                // Attribute - Effects
                Element Effects = document.createElement("Effects");
                Effects.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txteffects.getText()));
                Setting.appendChild(Effects);

                // Attribute - Pre Gain
                Element Pregain = document.createElement("Pregain");
                Pregain.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txtpregain.getText()));
                Setting.appendChild(Pregain);

                // Attribute - Low
                Element Low = document.createElement("Low");
                Low.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txtlow.getText()));
                Setting.appendChild(Low);

                // Attribute -Mid
                Element Mid = document.createElement("Mid");
                Mid.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txtmid.getText()));
                Setting.appendChild(Mid);

                // Attribute -High
                Element High = document.createElement("High");
                High.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txthigh.getText()));
                Setting.appendChild(High);

                // Attribute -Post Gain
                Element Postgain = document.createElement("Postgain");
                Postgain.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txtpostgain.getText()));
                Setting.appendChild(Postgain);

                // Attribute -Parameter 1
                Element Param1 = document.createElement("Param1");
                Param1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txtparam1.getText()));
                Setting.appendChild(Param1);

                // Attribute -Parameter 2
                Element Param2 = document.createElement("Param2");
                Param2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txtparam2.getText()));
                Setting.appendChild(Param2);

                // Attribute -Feedback
                Element Feedback = document.createElement("Feedback");
                Feedback.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txtfeedback.getText()));
                Setting.appendChild(Feedback);

                // Attribute -Level
                Element Level = document.createElement("Level");
                Level.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txtlevel.getText()));
                Setting.appendChild(Level);

                // Attribute -Reverb
                Element Reverb = document.createElement("Reverb");
                Reverb.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txtreverb.getText()));
                Setting.appendChild(Reverb);

                // Write the content into XML file
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("Settings.xml"));

                transformer.transform(source, result);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");

              } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
                pce.printStackTrace();
              } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
                tfe.printStackTrace();
              } catch (SAXException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    mnMenu.add(menuitemsave);
```

¿Any idea about why it seems to delete all the other childs except the first and then append?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce the situation that you described. The new *Setting* element was append and other elements are kept.
Maybe you should print `File("Settings.xml").getAbsolutePath()` and verify the file content again.

Comment: I exported the program as runnable jar and then I put the xml file in the same directory. It works. May be I missed the path as you said. Thanks for helping.